# woocommerce - custom price formatting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce to build a custom theme for a webshop. The price formatting that i'm getting back now is: '150' when the price is 150. This is what I want to achieve:

- price = '150,<sup>00</sup>' when price is filled in as '150'
- price = '150,<sup>50</sup>' when price is filled in as '150,50'
- price = '150,<sup>55</sup>' when price is filled in as '150,55'

So I want to add the ',' and two decimals in 'sup' tags. Seems pretty straightforward, but I can't get it done. Anyway here who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP function - `number_format()` for decimal points to convert in `,`

```
$n = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
```

For superscript, try below

Try this:-

```
$parts = explode(',', $price);
echo "$parts[0],<sup>$parts[1]</sup>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are you familiar with Woocommerce? Is this enough to do the trick or do I need to find the function/variables that woocommerce uses?

Comment: You can change format from woo commerce

WooCommerce > Settings > Catalog > Pricing Options

but for superscript, you have to do this trick

Comment: Where do I place it? In functions.php? Do I need to build a function around it?

Comment: If you can customize in woo commerce, you can put superscript code to that place, where price is getting called.

Comment: I'm calling it with: "echo $product->get_price_including_tax()", how can I add the superscript code to that?

Comment: $parts = explode(',', $product->get_price_including_tax());
echo "$parts[0],<sup>$parts[1]</sup>";